# how to log on a rails application with curl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

thanks for reading this.

I was wondering if I have some simple authentication system in place, like authlogic, how does one use curl to post and put data and, even before talking about posting and putting data, how does one "login" with curl and have the server remember or have curl remember that it is logged in?

if you were to choose, would you rather use XML or JSON to post data? And any advice on how to make this posting secure?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it

So to add that artcile with title and body.

**1) login:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://example.com/login -d "{\"user_session\" : { \"username\" : \"someuser\", \"password\" : \"somepassword\"}}" -c example_cook.txt
```

Because I am using Rails, I have to use json or xml so to avoid the need for authenticity token. Then I save the cook in `example_cook.txt` for the next step

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://example.com/articles -d "{\"articles\" : { \"title\" : \"lorem\", \"body\" : \"ipsum\"}}" -b example_cook.txt
```

calling the '-b example_cook.txt' will tell curl to use that session information which the server needs for authenticating you.

That's it!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Find the URI that the login form posts to, then `POST` the relevant data. For example:

```
curl -X POST -d 'login=foo&password=bar' http://example.com/login
```

Comment: say I did that, and then I wanted to add an article to rails by 

curl -X POST -d 'article[title]=itablet' -d 'article[body]=lorem ipsum' http://dns/articles

because the new action and the create action is 'behind' the layer of the authentication, will curl remember the 'session' that it got from logging in in the previous line?